# On the character of a representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, reductive-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}$Let $G=\GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Given a continuous admissible irreducible representation of $G$ in a Frechet (or a Banach) space. Then its character is well defined as a generalized function on $G$. It is known to be $\Ad(G)$-invariant.

**What is known on the structure of the character? Is it smooth on some subset? What is known on its singularities?** I am particularly  interested whether it has to be continuous (or even smooth) in a neighborhood of $-I_n$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix.

Sorry if the question is not of the research level.